# Simplified timezone shapefile suitable for Arduino?

Tags: time

Is there a library or shape file available that allows an Arduino to approximate a timezone based on a latitude/longitude coordinate? There is a [timezone shape file](http://efele.net/maps/tz/world/) available, but it's too detailed and too large. I am hoping someone knows of a simplified version small enough for an Arduino and/or a library that's able to handle this task.

Comment: It isn't what you asked for, but would web services like in http://stackoverflow.com/a/16086964/1653571 be feasible?  I'd try to use UTC and avoid timezones and DST if I can get away with it, and make the display TZ a user-configured option if I had to.

Comment: Really looking for an actual solution. If you look at timezone shapes graphically, they really aren't that complex if you are willing to overlook, say, detecting a wrong timezone when you're within 10km to a border. In that case, the timezone shapes reduce to probably no more than a few dozen shapes with maybe a dozen vertices each. Something an Arduino can handle.

Comment: Foursquare have an open-source tool to do that. https://github.com/foursquare/shapefile-geo